# Oracle random timestamp for specific date

Tags: oracle

In Oracle I'm generating random dates. Now I need, for each date, to generate a random TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL ZONE. This code only generates the current timestamp:

```
SYSDATE + dbms_random.value(0, SYSDATE - SYSDATE +1) INTO l_ran_time FROM dual;
```

Therefore I tried substituting SYSDATE with the name of the variable that contains the correct date, but I receive an error:

```
*Cause:    supplied scn was beyond the bounds of a valid scn.
*Action:   use a valid scn.
```

Can anyone  help me?

Comment: "Therefore I tried substituting", show how did you try it

Comment: Looks like you've hidden something, because in your snippet there're no things about SCN. Please, post all the code you use (including usage of `l_ran_time`).

Answer (score 0):

You may phrase your problem as saying that you want to add some random number of seconds between 0 and 24*60*60 to the current timestamp:

```sql
SELECT
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP +
    numToDSInterval(dbms_random.value(1, 24*60*60), 'second') AS random_ts
FROM dual;
```